# How to stop the compiler from deleting my function

Tags: c++, file

When I add a `return` statement to the end of my overloaded `operator=`, the compiler throws an error. It says:

> 'File::File(const File&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

However, when I delete the `return` statement (and the type specifier), no problem.

```
class File : public Document {
private:
    fstream mainFile;
    string drive, folder, fileName, fullPath;
protected:

public:
    File(string d, string f, string fn, string txt = "NULL") : Document(txt) {
        drive = d;
        folder = f;
        fileName = fn;
        if(fileName.find(".txt") == -1) {
            fileName.append(".txt");
        }
        fullPath = drive + ":/" + folder + "/" + fileName;
        mainFile.open(fullPath.c_str());
        mainFile << txt;
    }
    File() : Document() {
        drive = folder = fileName = "NULL";
        fullPath = drive + ":/" + folder + "/" + fileName;
    }

    File operator = (File & a) {
        this->getDrive() = a.getDrive();
        this->getFolder() = a.getFolder();
        this->getFileName() = a.getFileName();
        this->getText() = a.getText();
        this->fileName = a.fileName;
        return a;
    }

};
```

Comment: BTW, the `this->` notation is not necessary.  Only use it when a local variable or parameter has the same name as a member.  You can change parameter & local variables to avoid `this->`.  Also `this->` is not necessary to execute class methods.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string::npos` instead of -1 when checking the results of `find`.

Comment: You are trying to return a copy of the passed in reference. The class does not know how to construct a copy. You need to write a *copy constructor*.

Comment: The default definition is ill-formed because the default definition does a memberwise copy, and `fstream` objects cannot be copied. Therefore, the compiler doesn't know what to do with the `mainFile` member.

Answer (score 4):

```
File operator = (File & a) {
```

This operator is returning its result by value. That is, via a copy.

The problem is that the `File` contains a `std::fstream` member, which itself has a deleted copy constructor. It cannot be copied. A `std::fstream` represents a possibly open file. The concept of "copying" an open file is utterly meaningless, so file stream objects cannot be copied, and because of that `File` itself cannot be copied, since it contains a non-copyable class member, and that is the reason for the compilation error. An attempt is made to copy an uncopyable class.

Leaving out the `return` statement results in an undefined behavior, of a function that's declared as returning a `File` not returning anything.

This is all because of several fundamental problems with your implementation of an assignment operator. An assignment operator should:

- take a `const` parameter.
- return a ***reference*** to its own instance, and
- return `*this`.

In order to implement an assignment operator with the expected semantics it should be declared as

```
File &operator=(const File &a)
```

and finish its job by returning

```
    return *this;
```

Comment: *"The concept of 'copying' an open file is utterly meaningless"* -- I could see the argument that duplicating the file handle (`dup()`) would be a semantically valid interpretation of copying an fstream. So "meaningless" might be too strong a term. Nevertheless, that functionality is not provided -- via a copy ctor, anyway...

Comment: So I tried to make the parameters const, but the compiler throws an error saying that I'm discarding the qualifiers. However, inside the code, the const input is an R-Value, and thus should not be altered. Once the R-Value can be altered (with a second = sign) then the function should be closed and not worried about the const indicator.

Comment: All your other methods, `getDrive()`, et. al., must be `const` methods themselves. Since they should not, by definition, be modifying `this` -- they are getters and nothing more -- they must themselves be `const` methods. The best way to avoid bugs is to write your code in a manner that most bugs result in immediate compilation failures, rather than bizarre runtime behavior that ends up wasting a pile of time trying to figure out. And, as an extra bonus, all standard features of the C++ language, such as copy constructors will then automatically work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your copy operator should be:

```
File & operator=(File const &);
```

The compiler is complaining about `return a;` because the operator declares that it returns an object, not a reference -- so `a` needs to be copied.  But `mainFile` is an `std::fstream`, which provides no copy constructor of its own, and so the compiler cannot generate a copy constructor for you.  You didn't provide a copy constructor yourself, therefore `File` objects are uncopyable. This is why you get an error when returning `a`.

The correct implementation would be:

```
File & operator=(File const & a) {
    this->getDrive() = a.getDrive();
    this->getFolder() = a.getFolder();
    this->getFileName() = a.getFileName();
    this->getText() = a.getText();
    this->fileName = a.fileName;
    return *this;
}
```

Note that we additionally take the argument by const reference; this allows copy-assigning from `File` objects that are const (otherwise, you couldn't).  Further, the assignment operator is generally supposed to return a reference to the target of the assignment (which is `*this`, not `a`).

Comment: Don't forget to check for `&a != this` before copying anything: `File& operator=(File const &a) { if (&a != this) { ... } return *this; }`

Comment: Ok. So I put the pass by reference indicator in the return value, and it works alright. But doesn't that imply that the function can access the file's place in memory?

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci That is correct. `fstream` objects can't be copied directly. There are workarounds, however.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I consider that to be an anti-pattern. Copying an object to itself is a semantic error on the part of the caller, and it's not worth trying to optimize for that case -- only to ensure that the postconditions are still met.

Comment: @cdhowie: self-assignment is rare but not impossible. One could write the assignment to be check-less, but that usually involves making a copy regardless of self-assignment. And if a copy operation is generally expensive than a check for self-assignment can help performance in those cases.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's rare enough that I suspect the performance hit for performing the needless copy in the rare case is outweighed by avoiding a conditional jump in the common case.